# Laravel api routes with apiResource got 405 on update

Tags: php, laravel

I've got something unusual and I don't how it is. I need to hit update endpoint which like `.../api/majors/1` with 1 is `id` and method is PATCH. If I hit it for the first time, it run peacefully. And then I want to get the updated data with `.../api/majors/1` method GET. It returning the data like what we want it to return.

```
{
  "data": ...
}
```

And oops the data need to be update again, so we fill the form and hit `.../api/majors/1` method PATCH with all new data. But this time it got error:

`405 Method Not Allowed. The PATCH method is not supported for route /. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Is Laravel just guessing maybe I want to show the data instead of updating it? So it is expecting `.../api/majors/1` with GET method.

it also happens when we are trying to updating the non existing data, for the example we just have 4 rows of data, with id `1,2,3,4` but by mistake we hit `.../api/majors/9` with PATCH method. It gave `405 Method Not Allowed` and expecting GET method.

```
// routes/api.php

   Route::apiResource('/majors', MajorController::class);
```

```
// MajorController.php update

   public function update(int $id, UpdateMajorRequest $request) {
     $data = Major::findOrFail($id);
       
     try {
       $data->update($request->all());

       return response()->json("ok", 200);
     } catch (\Throwable $th) {
       return response()->json($th->getMessage(), 500);
     }
  }
```

Edit: please dont reply with add `method_field: PATCH|PUT` with POST method on request. I've tried it. I use postman to execute the api endpoint with headers: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` give you?

Comment: The error says you are trying to send `PUT|PATCH` to `/` path. Can you verify that?

Comment: route list give the route i want /majors/{majors} with PATCH to update method

Comment: Yes it is like laravel route it to / instead of /{majors}. So it will ask for GET method